# Rebooting without shutting off?

Tags: debian, kernel, boot, linux-mint

I have been using Linux Mint Debian with Debian unstable and noticed that when I press restart, instead of going all the way back to the BIOS, then grub, then booting up, I seem to be shutting down then loading back up without going back to the BIOS or GRUB.

This is an amazing feature I have not seen before until now. What is this called and when did it happen? I had been a user of Ubuntu for a long time.

Comment: Are you sure it's actually rebooting? It sounds like it's just restarting X

Comment: Yes I watch it all the way, shuts every thing off then begins right where a normal cold boot would

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It looks like your system has [kexec](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/linux/library/l-kexec/index.html) enabled. Kexec allows the Linux kernel to load another kernel and hand the system over to that system. It's named after the [`exec`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Execve) family of functions that replace a process by a new executable image. Instead of calling the `reboot` utility, your system is set up to call [`kexec`](http://linux.die.net/man/8/kexec) when you reboot, and the kernel does the rest.

Comment: Found that package in my system must be it. Awesome

Comment: Interesting. This can be enabled in Debian with `kexec-tools` (the stock Debian kernels have `kexec` support), and installation of `kexec-tools` enables `kexec` by default, though I have not tested it. Looks like Ubuntu (and Mint) have it by default. My system has debconf priority high, & I didn't see a debconf screen when enabling, so I conclude that the question is set to priority medium or low, though I forget how to check how to find out the debconf priority for a template. Would anyone like to remind me? Might be a reasonable question here - Google doesn't immediately provide an answer.

Comment: For the record, this is set in the config file, in this case `/var/lib/dpkg/info/kexec-tools.config`. See the line "db_input medium kexec-tools/load_kexec || true".

Comment: Just an hint: if you are using `kexec` and you need a "cold" reboot (i.e. passing through BIOS, ...), you can use `/sbin/coldreboot` (at least in Debian, it is part of `kexec-tools` package).